# How to dynamically format date on item-text inside v-autocomplete (Vuetify)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-autocomplete

I have this `v-autocomplete` which receives an array of items to display from `GrowthTasks.edges`

```
<v-autocomplete label="Start Week" 
:items="GrowthTasks.edges" item-text="node.growthStartDate" item-value="node.growthStartDate" dense></v-autocomplete>
```

The `item-text` receives the text  from there by acessing `node.growthStartDate`, which is a date format like : "2020-05-06".

Now I want to turn it into a format like "2020-W19" , which I know is possible using `moment("YYYY-[W]WW")` but I dont know how to tell this to `item-text`.

Basically, I want the result on the item-text to be the same as if I was using :

```
{{ node.growthStartDate | moment("YYYY-[W]WW") }}
```

which works.

Any idea on how can do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create computed property and return formated dates:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      GrowthTasks: {edges: [{growthStartDate: "2020-05-06"}, {growthStartDate: "2020-06-07"}]}
    }
  },
  computed: {
    items() {
      return this.GrowthTasks.edges.map(obj => ({ ...obj, growthStartDate: moment(obj.growthStartDate).format("YYYY-[W]WW") }));
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-autocomplete label="Start Week" 
:items="items" item-text="growthStartDate" item-value="growthStartDate" dense></v-autocomplete>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: at the moment it full fills the requirement but imagine, if he wants to formate the date on many other componants with different date formats then? The best way is to create a global filter and send it "desired formate date" as a parameter as in my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71374342/2959918

Answer (score 1):

You can use filters or methods using `v-slot:item`, If you want to pass a date to the `moment.js`, I suggest to use [Filters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html?redirect=true), you can register `filters` globally and can use them anywhere in your application.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      GrowthTasks: {edges: [{growthStartDate: "2020-05-06"}, {growthStartDate: "2020-06-07"}]}
    }
  },
  filters: {
    myDateFilter(date, desireFormat) {
      return moment(date).format(desireFormat);
    }
}
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
      
        <v-autocomplete label="Start Week" 
:items="GrowthTasks.edges" item-text="growthStartDate" item-value="growthStartDate" dense>
      <template v-slot:item="data">
       {{ data.item.growthStartDate |  myDateFilter('YYYY-[W]WW') }}
      </template>
</v-autocomplete>
      
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```